# Flutter image cropper not showing image to be cropped

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I managed to choose an image from gallery using the image picker and it is as follows

```
Future pickImage() async {
File _originalImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
    source: ImageSource.camera);
if (_originalImage != null) {
  File _croppedImage = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
      sourcePath: _originalImage.path,
      aspectRatioPresets: [
        CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
      ],

      androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
          toolbarColor: BaengColors.blue,
          toolbarTitle: 'Baeng Omang Cropper',
          statusBarColor: BaengColors.blue[700],
          initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
          lockAspectRatio: false
      )
  );
   this.setState(() {
     _imagePicked = _croppedImage;
     isLoaded = true;
     getTextFromImage();
    });
   } 
  }
```

Tried to debug it several times and it was not showing any kind of bug nor problem, but the image cropping activity remains black(without) the image selected from the image picker.

Please help

Comment: Are you testing on android or ios?

Comment: I am testing on an android device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just add maxHeight And maxWidth in Image_Picker**

```
File  _originalImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera, 
imageQuality: 20,
maxHeight: 500,maxWidth: 500);
```

Comment: you can add  imageQuality: 20, by your choice